# Adding methods to class and use them in other groovy code

Tags: groovy

I'm very new to Groovy. I have a class where I'm adding methods using `metaClass`. Here is the code I have for Parser.groovy:

```
PrivateClass.metaClass.convertDDTToMap { obj,fileLocation ->

}
```

where `PrivateClass` is a class coming from a jar. Now in other file named Hack.groovy I have the following code:

```
class Hack extends PrivateClass
{
//.. code
convertDDTToMap(param,param)
}
```

when I run Hack.groovy, I get the exception that the method `convertDDTToMap` is not there.

However `Parser.groovy` is in the same classpath and it gets compiled. But its not adding the method.

Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: What version are you using? When does `Parser.groovy` gets called? I made a [gist using inheritance](https://gist.github.com/will-lp/9386502) which works fine

Comment: groovy-2.2.0. `Parser.groovy` is in ant compilation path. And also the `Hack.groovy`. Both are under `src` directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parser.groovy being compiled only is doing nothing, the code there needs to be called. For example using new Parser().run()